# static initializer block return void

Tags: java, null, integer, static-initialization, static-initializer

I know that it isnt about my problem but just to you know, this is my first stackoverflow post and yes, my english isnt quite good so please, i sincerely ask you guys, be patience. I'd chosen english community because brazillian stack overflow community isnt this good as english version do.

About my problem, here it is:

```
public class Class5{

static int ia, ib;

public static Class5 InstanceClass5 = new Class5();

public Class5(){this(1, 2);}
public Class5(int ia){this(ia, 0);}
public Class5(int ia, int ib){this.ia = ia; this.ib = ib;}

// the only one important part of this class code
public static void returnConstructor(int ia, int ib){}
// ends here, the rest isnt important
public static int myVar = initializeClassVariable();
private static int initializeClassVariable(){int ia = 3; return ia;}
}

public class Main
{
static Scanner dataEntrance = new Scanner(System.in);

public Main(){}
public static Main Instancia1Main = new Main();

static int ia, ib;

// here my problem begins: i just did 2 static blocks initializers, but its working good.
public static int varType = InitializeClassVariable();
private static int InitializeClassVariable(){ia = Class5.ia; return ia;}
public static int varType2 = InitializeClassVariable2();
private static int InitializeClassVariable2(){ib = Class5.ib; return ib;}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(Class3.Instancia2Class3.Class3());

    // It shows that the first static block initializer is doing what it was created to do: get the same value as "ia" class variable,
    // inside Class5 (so, varType2 or InitializeClassVariable2 method is working by the same way, for sure)
    System.out.println(Main.varType);
    //final Main instancia1Main = Instancia1Main; -- it doenst have any importance for now
    // AND FINALLY, THERES MY PROBLEM: inside Class5, returnConstructor method have 2 arguments: int ia, int ib
    // To print this method values, i have to use 2 int arguments: why not varType and varType2 
    // or InitializeClassVariable and InitializeClassVariable2 (work by the same way... in theory)
    // It supposed to work then...
    System.out.println(Class5.InstanceClass5.returnConstructor(Main.InitializeClassVariable(), Main.varType2));
}
}
```

[Then it happens][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR8xH.png

I really got no idea why returnConstructor is receiving the listed arguments (Main.InitializeClassVariable(), Main.varType2) as void.
System.out.println(Main.varType); -> It shows that varType isnt a void, and varType2 for sure do the same, someone have any idea about why its happening and how to fix that?
I think thats all, thx everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`returnConstructor` doesn't return anything, so `println` has nothing to print.